# Exit selection not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to get enter, update and exit to work on my draw function. The enter and update work although I am having problems trying to get the exit to work properly.

Here is the code:

```
            var draw = function () {
            var drawData = function (dat, className, baseFill, area) {

                //var selection (supermarket)
                var supermarket, supermarketEnter;
                supermarket = svg.selectAll('.' + className)
                    .data(dat,
                        function (c) {
                            return c.Vendor;
                        });

                //var new selection (supermarketEnter)
                supermarketEnter = supermarket.enter()
                    .append('g')
                    .attr('class', className)
                    .attr('data-vendor', function (d) { return d.Vendor; })
                    .attr('width', width)
                    .attr('height', height);
                supermarketEnter.append('path');

                //update new selection
                supermarketEnter
                    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clipper)')
                    .attr('class', 'line')
                    .attr('id', function (d) { return d.Vendor; });

                supermarket.select('path')
                    .transition()
                    .attr('class', 'lines-data')
                    .attr('fill', 'none')
                    .duration(500)
                    .attr('d',
                        function (d) {
                            return line(d.Values);
                        });

                var path = supermarket.select('path')
                .style('stroke', function (d, i) {
                    return (d.Visible ? baseFill(d.Index) : grayFill);

                });
                if (area) {
                    path.style('fill', function (d, i) { return (d.Visible ? baseFill(d.Index) : grayFill); });

                }

                supermarketEnter
                    .selectAll("circle")
                    .data(function (d) {
                        return d.Values;
                    })
                        .enter()
                        .append('circle')
                        .attr('class', 'datapoint')
                        .attr('r', 4)
                        .style('fill',
                            function (d, i, j) {
                                return dat[j].Visible ? baseFill(j) : grayFill;
                            })
                        .attr('transform',
                            function (d) {
                                return 'translate(' + x(d.Month) + ',' + y(d.Value) + ')';
                            })
                        .on('mouseover',
                            function (d, i, j) {

                                d3.select('.tooltip')
                                    .style('opacity', '1');
                                d3.select('.tooltip')
                                    .html(dat[j].Vendor + '<br/> (' + moment(d.Month).format("MMM YYYY") + ', ' + d.Value.toPrecision(2) + '% )')
                                    .style('left', function () {
                                        var newWidth = d3.event.pageX - ($(chartEl).width() / 10) + 'px';
                                         if (window.innerWidth >= 1200) {
                                           var  newWidth = d3.event.pageX - ($(chartEl).width() / 2) + 'px';
                                        }
                                        return newWidth;
                                    })
                                    .style('top', (d3.event.pageY) - 300 + 'px');


                            })
                        .on("mouseout",
                            function (d) {

                                d3.select('.tooltip')
                                    .style('transition', '500')
                                    .style('opacity', 0)
                                    .style('color', d3.select(this).style('fill'));
                            });


                supermarket.exit().remove();
                supermarket.order();

                return zoomBeh.x(x);
            }

            svg.selectAll('.x.axis').call(xAxis);
            svg.selectAll('.y.axis').call(yAxis);


            drawData(chartData, 'supermarket', patterns, false);

        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "exit" selection is based on this block, which binds the data:

```
supermarket = svg.selectAll('.' + className)
    .data(dat, function(c){
        return c.Vendor;
    });
```

Pay attention to this part: `selectAll('.' + className)`. Here, we select all elements with a class named `.className` (whatever string `className` is) and bind the data to them.

Moving on: initially, your "enter" selection correctly sets the class:

```
supermarketEnter = supermarket.enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', className)
```

But then, few lines below, you do this:

```
supermarketEnter
    .attr('class', 'line')
```

And you overwrite the `.className` class.

Thus, your exit selection is always empty, because there is no class named `className` anymore.

**Demonstration:**

Check this first snippet, with the correct selections. You can se that both "enter" and "exit" selections work:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

setInterval(function(){
var data = d3.range(Math.random()*20);
draw(data);
}, 1000);

function draw(data){

var circles = svg.selectAll(".someClass")
 .data(data);
 
var circlesEnter = circles.enter().append("circle")
 .attr("class", "someClass")
 .attr("cx", (d,i)=> 10 + i*15)
 .attr("cy", 50)
 .attr("r", 5)
 .attr("fill", "teal");
 
var circlesUpdate = circles.attr("cx", (d,i)=> 10 + i*15);

var circlesExit = circles.exit().remove();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Now, the same code, but overwriting the initial class:

```
circlesEnter.attr("class", "foo");
```

You can see that the "exit" selection doesn't work anymore. It's a broken code:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

setInterval(function(){
var data = d3.range(Math.random()*20);
draw(data);
}, 1000);

function draw(data){

var circles = svg.selectAll(".someClass")
 .data(data);
 
var circlesEnter = circles.enter().append("circle")
 .attr("class", "someClass")
 .attr("cx", (d,i)=> 10 + i*15)
 .attr("cy", 50)
 .attr("r", 5)
 .attr("fill", "teal");
 
circlesEnter.attr("class", "foo");
 
var circlesUpdate = circles.attr("cx", (d,i)=> 10 + i*15);

var circlesExit = circles.exit().remove();

}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```